# TestFlight build to client

Tags: ios, testflight

So, I'm working on an app as an admin on the project, and I want to get a beta build to the client.

I have selected the correct Development Team, but then it says No accounts with iTunes Connect access. iTunes Connect access for "XXXXXXXX" is required. Add an account in the Accounts preference pane.

Remember, this is not my personal project, and I'm developing for someone else.

My role is an "Admin" of the team on developer.apple.com if that matter.s

I don't even know how to phrase this question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in with Apple developer account to sign the application and send beta build to user via TestFlight.

You can login into Xcode as given below steps.

[image]

[image]

**Note :** You need to sign in with developer Apple ID and password.

Comment: Yes, I get that. I’m signed in with my personal account. Is this also the account I use for the team? I would have thought there’s a different one for that.

Comment: No. You need to use apple developer account by which you have created provisioning profile to sign the application. The other option is you can ask admin to add you as a developer in their team so then again generate provisioning profiles and this way you will be able to send beta to your client.